# apc.enable_cli after Homebrew installation

Tags: homebrew, apc

how can I enable apc.enable_cli after installing php54-apc with Homebrew on a osX?
I tried to add it inside my php.ini, but it doesn't work.

Although this, I can properly edit params like apc.gc_ttl inside my php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Here it is the solution.
Change the apc configs inside this file:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d/ext-apc.ini
```